# Updating a Location of character in simple 2D Python game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d

Please help me to write the procedure `updateLocn(x,y,state)` so that the character at (x,y) in the map is changed to the chosen state. I tried writing on my own, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

T=Trees;
G=Goblin who steals your items;
g=Box with gold;
~=River;
w=Wall;
-=Floor;
b=Empty box;
= =Locked door;
k=Key for locked doors;
*=Exit door

```py
worldMap = [
"TTTT TTTT g  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
"T        gT  w----=---b--=bgw",
"TTTTGTTT     =----w------w-gw",
"TTTTTTTTTTT kwwwwwwwwwwwww*ww",
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T TT",
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T TT",
"                    ~~~~~    ",
"                    ~~~~~    "]

def printMap():
    global worldMap 
    for line in worldMap:
        print(line)

def getLocn(x,y):
    global worldMap
    locn = worldMap[y][x]
    return locn
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return None

def describeLocn(x,y):
    global worldMap
    locn = getLocn(x,y)
    if locn == "T":<br/>
        return ("Dense forest")
    elif locn == "t":
        return ("Light woods")
    elif locn == "w":
        return ("Wall")
    else :
        return ("Meadows") 
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return None
```

```py
def updateMap(x,y,newState):
    global worldMap
    locn = getLocn(x,y)
    locn = newState
    newState = list(worldMap)
    worldMap = ''.join(newState)
```

The last procedure is my trial code. I should use x,y, newState variables here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues first off: when you assign a variable twice, the first one might as well not be assigned. 
My suggestion is to seperate the update of the location from the flag of the place(your meaning of what you want to have there) to the place of it in the world.

For example if you want to insert a new state newstate at x,y:

```
def updateLocn(x,y,newstate):
    global worldMap
    If x<0 or y<0:
        Handle the exception(usually using raise IndexError(errorstr))
    worldMap[y][x]=newstate
```

This should work up to how you handle going in negative indexes. 
Keep in mind when you access an element of a list, changing it won't alter the list. You must alter the list at the correct indexes.

Additionally, checking the parameters should come first, not last. In getlocn the check on x,y will never occur because you return whatever you found there first.

Comment: `global worldMap` is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

> ```py
> locn = worldMap[y][x]
> locn = state
> ```

then this does not change an element of `worldMap`. This statements get and element of `worldMap` to the local variable `locn` and then the variable `locn` is changed.

You have to assign an value to an element of `worldmap`:

```py
def updateMap(x,y,newState):
    worldMap[y][x] = newState
```

Answer (score 0):

```
worldMap = [
"TTTT TTTT g  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
"T        gT  w----=---b--=bgw",
"TTTTGTTT     =----w------w-gw",
"TTTTTTTTTTT kwwwwwwwwwwwww*ww",
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T TT", 
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T TT",
"                    ~~~~~    ",
"                    ~~~~~    "]
for line in worldMap:
    print( line )
def printMap():
'''Display the wolrdMap'''
    global worldMap 

for line in worldMap:
    print(line)

def updateMap(x,y,state):
'''To change an object at a location'''
    global worldMap
    worldMap[y] = worldMap[y][:x] + state + worldMap[y][(x+y):]

    for line in worldMap:
        print(line)

    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        raise IndexError
```